# htaccess subdirectory URLS to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all files in a subdirectory to their new root URL.

Old URLS are

```
www.domain.com/subdirectory/filename-here.html
```

New location is

```
www.domain.com/filename.here.html
```

Old URLs are listed in Google already and need some sort of redirect for these.
I'm sure htaccess is the way to go here, but unsure of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectory/.*
RewriteRule subdirectory/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Tested on [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). If it would not work - add shielding to `[^/]` in this way: `[^\/]`

Comment: Almost perfect... links that are in a subdirectory also get's redirected to root.

E.g. 

www.domain.com/subdirectory/subdirectory2/filename.html

should be

www.domain.com/subdirectory2/file.html 

Possible?

Comment: You want to remove only one subdirectory?

Comment: Yes please, I would like that :)